# mount: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host

Tags: linux, mount, remote

I'm trying to mount folder from my virtual machine to embedded device with custom linux (BusyBox).
I use command

```
mount -o port=2049,nolock,proto=tcp,ro -t nfs "VM_IP:/home/user_name" "/mnt/nfs/user_name"
```

But I have following error:

```
mount: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host mount: mounting
VM_IP:/home/user_name on /mnt/nfs/user_name failed: Bad file descriptor
```

I've checked, I can ping my VM machine perfectly.

iptables on embedded device has following settings:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FILTER_CHAIN
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j FILTER_CHAIN
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j FILTER_CHAIN
-A INPUT -i bond0 -j FILTER_CHAIN
-A FILTER_CHAIN -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FILTER_CHAIN -p udp -m multiport --dports 161,162,4050 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTER_CHAIN -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21,22,23,80,4517 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTER_CHAIN -p tcp -m multiport --dports 9091,9100,15080,29100,42000 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTER_CHAIN -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22000:22010 -j ACCEPT
-A FILTER_CHAIN -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

nfs-server is successfully started on my VM.

**VM and device are in different subnetworks.**

Could you advise some workaround for this situation?

Comment: You said you can ping the IP, but are you able to connect to the port you configured NFS to use?  Your mount command specifies port 2049, but I do not see that port 2049 is open in those iptables rules.  Does it work without the firewall?

Comment: @GracefulRestart oh, iptables was reset. But I've tried to add this port to iptables rules and I still have this issue.

Comment: As your VM and device are in separate subnets, what sits between them? If a firewall, what are the rules in place for communication between the networks?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions!!! Problem was on VM side, iptables was blocking 111 and 2049 ports.